# StackSets with SERVICE_MANAGED permission model can only have OrganizationalUnit as target

Tags: aws-cli

I writing a AWS CLI delete script as below to delete service managed accounts

```
$opsResponse = aws cloudformation --region $region.RegionName delete-stack-instances --call-as DELEGATED_ADMIN  --stack-set-name $stackDetails.StackSetName --accounts $accountIds  --regions $multiDeleteRegions --no-retain-stacks --operation-preferences MaxConcurrentCount=1 | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Error I am getting

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the DeleteStackInstances operation: StackSets with SERVICE_MANAGED permission model can only have OrganizationalUnit as target
```

I tried adding `--organizational-unit-id $ouId` but that did not work.

Any idea how to delete service managed accounts via cli?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/delete-stack-instances.html

Used `--deployment-targets`

```
$opsResponse = aws cloudformation --region $region.RegionName delete-stack-instances --call-as DELEGATED_ADMIN  --stack-set-name $stackDetails.StackSetName --deployment-targets Accounts=$accountIds,OrganizationalUnitIds=$ouId,AccountFilterType=UNION  --regions $multiDeleteRegions --no-retain-stacks --operation-preferences MaxConcurrentCount=1 | ConvertFrom-Json
```